# IE and remember password prompt in web app

Tags: asp.net, forms, internet-explorer

I have a web app that has text and password input. When i use it to log in IE does not prompt me to remember password. I clear cookies and still do not get prompt. I have also selected all the options in the Content-> Autocomplete settings. 
Autocomplete works on another site ie facebook for example.

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server" onsubmit="javascript:return validateForm()">
   <asp:Panel ID="ViewPanel" runat="server" DefaultButton="btnLogin">

     <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 370px;">
                            <div style="text-transform: uppercase; color: #C00; font-weight: bold; font-size: 12px;
                                margin-bottom: 10px;">
                                Login</div>
                            <div class="loginbox">
                                <div style="color: #fff; font-weight: bold; margin-bottom: 5px;">
                                    Username / ID
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <input type="text" maxlength="100" name="Username" class="txt" />
                                </div>
                                <div style="color: #fff; font-weight: bold; margin-bottom: 5px;">
                                    Password
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <input type="password" maxlength="100" name="Password" class="txt" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="btn-login" align="center">
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="btnLogin" class="btn" runat="server">Login</asp:LinkButton>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>   
              </tr>
       </table>    

  </asp:Panel>
</form>
```

Comment: check your browser settings.

Comment: @Arun_C_C I have also selected all the options in the Content-> Autocomplete settings.

Comment: What happens if you change the LinkButton to just a button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote extensively on this topic here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/09/11/troubleshooting-stored-login-problems-in-ie.aspx

Your markup looks okay, so my guess would be that it's related to a no-cache header. Can you provide a live repro URL?